# Envoy proxy + Keycloak + JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, keycloak, envoyproxy

There is a keycloak: http://IP:8080/
There's an envoy with a working config that redirects all requests to Keycloak:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /dev/null
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8443
    listener_filters:
    - name: "envoy.filters.listener.tls_inspector"
    filter_chains:
    - filter_chain_match:
      filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: keycloak
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: proxy-keycloak
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: server.crt
              private_key:
                filename: server.key
  clusters:
  - name: proxy-keycloak
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    connect_timeout: 10s
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: proxy-keycloak
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 8080
```

There's an official example configuration for authenticating with a JWT token.

```
providers:
   provider1:
     issuer: issuer1
     audiences:
     - audience1
     - audience2
     remote_jwks:
       http_uri:
         uri: https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json
         cluster: example_jwks_cluster
         timeout: 1s
   provider2:
     issuer: issuer2
     local_jwks:
       inline_string: jwks_string

rules:
   # Not jwt verification is required for /health path
   - match:
       prefix: /health

   # Jwt verification for provider1 is required for path prefixed with "prefix"
   - match:
       prefix: /prefix
     requires:
       provider_name: provider1

   # Jwt verification for either provider1 or provider2 is required for all other requests.
   - match:
       prefix: /
     requires:
       requires_any:
         requirements:
           - provider_name: provider1
           - provider_name: provider2
```

Currently, if I send a POST request to http://ip:8080/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token with parameters: grant_type: password, client: custody-rest-api, username: testuser1, password: test1, I receive a token. If I send a GET request containing this token to http://IP:9084/api/v1/access/hello-2 (Spring Security API), I get a 200 response.

There is a microservice at IP:9081/swagger-ui/index.html.

I need to configure Envoy so that when accessing IP:9081/swagger-ui/index.html, Envoy checks the JWT token. If the JWT token is missing or invalid, it should redirect to the Keycloak authentication page. After successful authentication, it should redirect to the page IP:9081/swagger-ui/index.html itself.

I've read the documentation, but it might still be a bit challenging for me. I've tried some internet-provided options, but there are very few. Often, Envoy crashes with errors related to filters. Maybe someone has a reliably working config, or someone can help put one together?"

It seems like you're working on configuring Envoy for JWT-based authentication and authorization, particularly for access to a Swagger UI microservice through Keycloak. It's a bit complex, especially with the configuration intricacies involved. How can I assist you further?

Expected outcome seems to be that when accessing the Swagger UI microservice (IP:9081/swagger-ui/index.html), Envoy should intercept the request, check for a valid JWT token, and if the token is missing or invalid, redirect the user to the Keycloak authentication page. Upon successful authentication, the user should be redirected back to the Swagger UI page (IP:9081/swagger-ui/index.html) with access granted.